# What Self Balancing Tree is simplest in Functional Programming?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tree, tree-balancing

I'm designing a self balancing tree in Haskell. As an exercise and because it is nice to have in your back hand.

Previously in C and Python I preferred Treaps and Splay Trees due to their simple balancing rules. I always disliked R/B Trees, since they seemed like more work than they were worth.

Now, due to the functional nature of Haskell, things seem to have changed. I can write a R/B insert function in 10 lines of code. Treaps on the other hand requires wrapping to store the random number generator, and Splay Trees are a pain to do top-down.

So I'm asking if you have experience with other types of trees?
Which ones are better at utilizing the pattern matching and top-down nature of functional languages?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but have a read of "Purely Functional Data Structures" to get some good ideas.

Comment: I like it. It doesn't go much into detailed structures, but offer a good general point of view.

Comment: Do you need a search tree, or a tree representation of a sequence (like fingertrees - with concatenation and splitting)? In the latter case, purely functional 2-3 trees are trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I guess there wasn't a lot of references or research for answering this question. Instead I've taken the time to try your different ideas and trees. I didn't find anything a lot better than RB trees, but perhaps that's just search bias.

The RB tree can be (insertion) balanced with four simple rules, as [shown by Chris Okasaki](http://www.eecs.usma.edu/webs/people/okasaki/jfp99.ps):

```
balance T (T R (T R a x b) y c) z d = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance T (T R a x (T R b y c)) z d = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance T a x (T R b y (T R c z d)) = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance T a x (T R (T R b y c) z d) = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance T a x b = T B a x b
```

AVL trees can be balanced in a similar pattern matching way. However the rules don't compress as well:

```
balance T (T (T a x b   dx) y c (-1)) z d (-2) = T (T a x b dx) y (T c z d  0) 0
balance T a x (T b y (T c z d   dz)   1 )   2  = T (T a x b  0) y (T c z d dz) 0
balance T (T a x (T b y c   1 )   1 ) z d (-2) = T (T a x b -1) y (T c z d  0) 0
balance T (T a x (T b y c (-1))   1 ) z d (-2) = T (T a x b  0) y (T c z d  1) 0
balance T (T a x (T b y c   _ )   1 ) z d (-2) = T (T a x b  0) y (T c z d  0) 0
balance T a x (T (T b y c   1 ) z d (-1))   2  = T (T a x b -1) y (T c z d  0) 0
balance T a x (T (T b y c (-1)) z d (-1))   2  = T (T a x b  0) y (T c z d  1) 0
balance T a x (T (T b y c   _ ) z d (-1))   2  = T (T a x b  0) y (T c z d  0) 0
balance t = t
```

As AVL trees seams to generally be considered inferior to RB trees, they are probably not worth the extra hassle.

AA trees could theoretically be balanced nice and easily by:

```
balance T n (T n a x b) y c = T n a x (T n b y c) -- skew
balance T n a x (T n b y (T n c z d)) = T (n+1) (T n a x b) y (T n c z d) --split
balance T n a x b = T n a x b
```

But unfortunately Haskell don't like the overloading of `n`. It is possible that a less standard implementation of AA trees, not using ranks, but something more similar to R and B, would work well.

Splay trees are difficult because you need to focus on a single node, rather than the static structure of the tree. It can be done by [merging insert and splay](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-October/085377.html).

Treaps are also uneasy to do in a functional environment, as you don't have a global random generator, but need to keep instances in every node. This can be tackled by [leaving the task of generating priorities to the client](http://hpaste.org/46259/treaps?pid=46259&lang_46259=Haskell#17), but even then, you can't do priority comparison using pattern matching.

Answer (score 6):

As you say Red Black trees aren't that hard to use.  Have you given [finger trees a look](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree)?  You might be interested in augmenting your base data structure with something like a [zipper.](http://scientopia.org/blogs/goodmath/2010/01/13/zippers-making-functional-updates-efficient/)   Another tree you might find interesting is the [AA tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_tree) it is a simplification of Red Black Trees.

Comment: Finger Trees look really cool. I'm very happy you let me discover this data structure.
They do however not look particularly simple to implement. Most implementations I've seen use a 2-3 tree and generalizes the tree for a lot of use cases.

Comment: You may be interested in AA trees, they are just simplified red black trees.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me at AA trees, I love them! Unfortunately their use of rank doesn't work well with pattern matching :(

Answer (score 4):

It's the one that's already implemented.

There are fine implementations in Haskell of balanced trees such as Data.Map and Data.Set. Don't they fulfill your needs? Don't reimplement, reuse.

Comment: For algorithmic purposes it often happens, that you need a tree, that stores specific information in each node. Be it the size of the subtrees in a statistic tree, or the right most point in an interval tree.

Answer (score 1):

The OCaml standard library uses an AVL tree for its `map` functor.  It seems as though it's easier to implement than an RB-tree if you include a `remove` operation.